# Get build result of a Azure DevOps build using Rest API

Tags: rest, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get the result of a Azure DevOps build i.e Succeeded / Failed via the REST API, so that I can use the result to queue the next build or not.

I have used the below powershell script to get the build details. But the status only provides the information if the build 'Completed' or not, we do not get the information if the build succeeded or not.

```
$Urinew = "https://<Org>/<project>/_apis/build/builds/"
$Uri2 = $Urinew+$buildId+"?api-version=5.0"
$responseFromGet = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri2 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)}
Write-host $responseFromGet
$status = $responseFromGet.status
```

I have tried to use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#buildresult) to get the build result. Tried to get the build definition too, but that also does not provide the information of the build Result. I tried the logs too, again same issue. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `status` is what the current status of the build (in progress, completed etc. ), the result status is in the property `result` , check your `responseFromGet.result`.